# The values are getting stored in "arr" correctly but garbage values are getting stored in "str". I do not understand why

Tags: c++

The values are getting stored in "arr" correctly but garbage values are getting stored in "str". I do not understand why. I checked it many times and it seems right to me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int test,n,arr[50],str[20][20],i,j,k;
    t = 0;
    j = 0;
    cin>>test; //test cases
    while(test>0){
        cin>>n; //number of elements in a test case 
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>arr[i]; //array of elements
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            cout<<"arr = "<<arr[i]<<"\n";
            str[i][j] = arr[i]; // storing arr in str
        }
        cout<<"\n";
        str[i+1][j] = 0;
        j++;
        test--;
    }
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        for(k=0;str[i][k]!=0;k++)
            cout<<<<str[i][k];  // printing str
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use your debugger and look at the values.

Comment: I am looking at all the values, the values are getting stored in "arr" correctly but when I am printing "str", garbage values are being displayed. I think I am doing some mistake while assigning the values to str.

Comment: You shouldn't use `0` as null terminator in other that `char` array.

Comment: Actually, I am manually storing "0" at the end of every row in "str", so that I can use it to determine the end of row. According to my program "0" will not be stored in that array. So I thought it would be good if I used that as a means to locate the end of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes but the main one is the indexing of a 2d array

A two dimensional array is like this **arr [row] [column]** and you have been using it like **arr [column] [row]**

```
 str[i][j] = arr[i];
```

see what u are doing is storing a number at every row

maybe this image will clear things out

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
using std :: cin ;
using std :: cout ; 
using std :: endl ;

int main() {
    int test,n,arr[50],str[20][20],i,j,k;
    j = 0;
    cin>>test; //test cases
    int temp = test ;
    while(test>0)
    {
        cin>>n; //number of elements in a test case 

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>arr[i]; //array of elements

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cout<<"arr = "<<arr[i]<<"\n";
            str[j][i] = arr[i]; // storing arr in str
        }

        str[j][i] = '\0';
        cout<<"\n";

        j++;
        test--;
    }

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < temp ; i++ )
    {
        j=0 ;
    while ( str[i][j] != '\0')
       {
           cout<<str[i][j];  // printing str
            j++ ;
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    cin.ignore(5) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you never use 't', so I removed that.
What I found was that it isn't actually outputting garbage values, it is just outputting the values in the wrong order. If you swap k and i at the end, it should work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int test,n,arr[50],str[20][20],j,i,k;
    j = 0;
    cin>>test; //test cases
    while(test>0){
        cin>>n; //number of elements in a test case 
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>arr[i]; //array of elements
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            cout<<"arr = "<<arr[i]<<"\n";
            str[j][i] = arr[i]; // storing arr in str
        }
        cout<<"\n";
        str[j+1][i] = 0;
        j++;
        test--;
    }
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        for(k=0;str[k][i]!=0;k++){
            cout<<str[k][i]<< ' ';  // printing str
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the input is wrong too , as he is adding a number to every row

Comment: I had realised that, I must've forgotten to change it in the code, I just changed it now.